# What's the difference between meteor reset and rm -rf .meteor/local?

Tags: meteor

What is the difference between `meteor reset` and `rm -rf .meteor/local` when run in a Meteor app dir?

Sometimes I just do `rm -rf .meteor/local` because it is wayyyyyy faster than `meteor reset`, but I'd love to understand how they differ.

Answer (score 2):

`meteor reset` also helps fixing build problems for example. Some `Meteor` versions ago this was a really essential thing because there were some issues with building to different platforms for example.
In general, you should not need it. Just `rm -rf .meteor/local` (bash) or `db.dropDatabase()` (`MongoDB` shell) is enough for reseting the project.
For more information, you can check the `Meteor` source code for this part: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/tools/cli/commands.js#L1182

Answer (score 0):

`meteor reset` is performed to reset your project. The data from your databases or rather from **Collections** also gets deleted.

`rm -rf .meteor/local` the files gets removed from Meteor local storage or (temp) directory.

Hope it will help you